# Cannot dynamically load Context Variables

Tags: talend

I am trying to **load the Context Variables dynamically** with the data from database but I am not able to load the context variables in **Talend**.

My Job flow is
[image]

My Schema of the Oracle Output is 
Column1 - BigDecimal
Column2 - BigDecimal

I am trying to load these values to the contexts I had created

Please anyone help on this issue why the context variables are not loaded.

Also I am not able to edit the schema of tContextLoad

**Edit:** I had edited my Schema as Key - String and Value - String by taking the values a String from database but still tContextLoad does not load the Context Variables it loads only the Key and the value

**Edit 1:** I had converted the BigDecimal to String in the Database Query itself so no need of loading BigDecimal in Context Variables, I need the Col1 - String DB value (mutiple values) to be stored in Var1 - String Context Variable and Col2 - String DB Value (Multiple Values) in Var2 - String Context Variable

**Edit 3:** Updated Workflow to handle multiple values
[image: Mutiple DB Values Job]

Comment: Are you getting an error ? Also, what is the schema of your table ?

Comment: @IbrahimMezouar I am getting the error key cannot be resolved or is not a field The Schema of my table is Col1 - Bigdecimal, Col2 - BigDecimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Schema of the Oracle Output is Column1 - BigDecimal Column2 - BigDecimal

This is the problem : tContextLoad will only accept a schema key/value, key and value both of String type.

You must change the name and type of the column you get from the database (in the query for instance).

> Also I am not able to edit the schema of tContextLoad.

Yes, it's one of the component that has defined columns (indicated with green).

Comment: I had taken the BigDecimal Value from DB as Key,Value as String but still the tContextLoad is not loading the Context Variables I get the message tContextLoad_1 set key "1" with value "0" only the key and the value is loaded the context Variables are not loaded

Comment: @Rajesh Can you give me an example for one of your key/value pair ? It sounds like you get only values from the DB and you have the keys elsewhere ?

Comment: Yes you are right both are values only I need those values to be stored in the context variables Var1 - String and Var2 - String but the tContextLoad is not loading the context variables and another one thing I get 32 rows as Input from the database

Comment: @Rajesh OK, so you have a context variable Var1 that you want to populate with a BigDecimal BigDecimal1 coming from your DB. Do you need to associate different context variables (Var1, Var2 ...) with different BigDecimal from the _same column (multiple rows)_ or do you want to associate them with BigDecimal from _different columns (same row)_ ?

Comment: I had converted the BigDecimal to String in the Database Query itself so no need of loading BigDecimal in Context Variables, I need the Col1 - String DB value (mutiple values) to be stored in Var1 - String Context Variable and Col2 - String DB Value (Multiple Values) in Var2 - String Context Variable

Comment: @Rajesh, Okay. You said you have multiple values from the DB that you want to store in a context variable. Is the variable supposed to store the concatenation or is it supposed to store each value, use it (with an iterate) and then store the next value ?

Comment: The Context Variable is supposed to store each individual values from the Multiple Values For your information I also tried with single value for context values assignment but still the context variables are not loaded for single values also.

Comment: I had skipped the Context Variables and used the global variables instead Thanks for sharing your knowledge

Comment: @Rajesh Perfect then !